# Regex to match just exact words Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

What would be the regular expression to find exact words, while excluding compounded words that contain the searched string.

For example I would like to match the string "wood floor" in "best wood floor" but not "hardwood floor", "hardwood flooring" "best hardwood floor".

Answer (score 3):

#### What is the regular expression to find exact words, excluding compounded words?

> I would like to match the string "wood floor" in "best wood floor" but not "hardwood floor", "hardwood flooring" "best hardwood floor".

- Menu "Search" > "Find" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `\<wood floor\>`
- Enable "Regular expression".
- Click "Find Next" or "Find All in Current Document".

Notes:

- `\<` matches the start of a word using Scintilla's definitions of words.
- `\>` matches the end of a word using Scintilla's definition of words.

[image]

---

#### Further reading

- [FAQ Desk: Where to find REGEX documentation ? | Notepad++ Community](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15765/faq-desk-where-to-find-regex-documentation)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)
- [RegExper: Regular Expression Visualiser](https://regexper.com/)

Comment: A couple of the links as "Further reading" are broken. Maybe editing the links with an archived version, may help? or this -->https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15765/faq-desk-where-to-find-regex-documentation

Comment: @TedTaylorofLife Thanks. Updating answer.

Comment: No, thank you for all that you do.